# Add a form-field to a PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

I would like to create a pdf with an editable text field.
In other words, a pdf that I can open in Adobe Reader and enter text at  a specific location. Is this somehow possible with Mathematica ?

A form field like here:

[image]

If it works with a command line tool, that's also fine !

Here is code to generate a "white paper" without the text field of course:

```
paper = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}];
Export["test.pdf", paper]
```

**EDIT:**
My platform is Windows 10.
Any external software is fine, as long as it is free.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible.

Comment: @Szabolcs It would be nice, though... Maybe by interfacing mathematica with some other program.

Comment: I think something can be done using LaTeX and the package ["hyperref"](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-200006). By the way, that is possible in R/RStudio with the package ["knitr"](https://yihui.name/knitr/) (which loads "hyperref" automatically.)

Comment: Since it can't be done without external software, you should probably specify what platform you're on, and perhaps narrow down the software you're willing to install. Eg. Acrobat (non-free), LaTeX (free but may be overkill), ...

Comment: @Jens Thanks, I will do that!

Comment: As of 12.2 you can import form fields